# Spring Boot / MySql :: SQLException: Access denied for user 'user1'@'dhcp-etc' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, amazon-rds

**After reading and trying the answers of similar posts, I do want to ask this question. Has my issue to do with migrating to spring boot 2.0.0?**

After creating any MySql database, locally or RDS AWS, I cannot get my Spring Boot 2.0.0 application connected to it. I still see that the exception: ... Access denied for user ... (using password: YES).

**IMPORTANT**: With the following simple Java program I could !! access the AWS RDS MySql database. I could also create tables, etc.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
// Username and password created via MySQL workbench
String username = "dbuser";
String password = "dbpassword";
String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://myhostname:3306/mydatabase?user=" + username + "&password=" + password;
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectStmt);
```

With a simple Spring Boot 2.0.0 application, I cannot get connected. First I get this error:

> 2018-12-25 10:36:59.670 ERROR 7184 --- [           main]
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception
>   during pool initialization.
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user
>   'dbuser'@'dhcp-etc' (using password: YES)

Further down I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory Caused by:
>
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory Caused by:
>
> **org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC
>   Connection for DDL execution Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access
>   denied for user 'dbsetup'@'dhcp-ipaddress-etc-.nl' (using password:
>   YES)**

And:

> org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not
>   get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to
>   obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:
>   Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'dhcp-etc' (using password: YES)

This is my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://myhostname:3306/mydatabase
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpassword
#REMOVED: spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Using this addition to the connection string does not have any effect: ?useSSL=false

My pom.xml contains:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

// anything related to databases: 

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

// I also tried version 5.1.40
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.11</version> <!-- without this version, same results -->
</dependency>
```

After connecting correctly from my PC (with Spring Boot) I will continue to develop with an EC2 instance.

AWS RDS MySQL version: 5.6.41.

Comment: please see my answer if still not work, can you try to connect RDS instance from your EC2 instance using same credentials where you installed spring boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let parent load its compatible mysql connector lib so try without version..

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with complete error logs

Comment: Also I think port is not required at RDS instance name just check it out and also try with dbname?useSSL=false

Comment: I will check it out with same versions, what mysql version you are using on RDS, and could you please also remove spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect as it will auto load dialect or use 5 or 57Dialect, one more thing please debug if there is something else logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG(add it in application.properties), error message shown password is wrong or not have enough permission to connect but you are able to connect with other clients so seems strange..

Comment: Version added. mysqldialect removed. Logging.debug added. Extra message added. Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Check your application.properties file carefully, there should not be any space after your DB username or password.
or, you can write in this way :
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?user=dbuser&password=dbpassword